# Select multiple rows to columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want below output through SQL server.

TABLE A

```
| Id   |   Name   | 2016 | 2017 |  
 - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
| 1    |  ABCDEFG |      |      |
| 2    |  XYZLMON |      |      |
```

TABLE B

```
| Id   | Value | Year |  
 - - - - - - - - - - -
| 1    |  F    | 2016 |
| 1    |  G    | 2017 |
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Id   |   Name   | 2016 | 2017 |  
 - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
| 1    |  ABCDEFG |  F   |  G   |
| 2    |  XYZLMON |      |      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    tbla.id as Id, 
    tbla.name as Name, 
    (SELECT 
        value 
     FROM tblb 
     WHERE tblb.Id = tbla.id 
     AND tblb.Year ='2016') as 2016, 
     (SELECT 
          value 
      FROM tblb 
      WHERE tblb.Id = tbla.id 
      AND tblb.Year ='2017') as 2017 
FROM tbla;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two joins:

```
select a.*, b2016.value as val2016, b2017.value as val2017
from a left join
     b b2016
     on a.id = b.id and b.year = 2016 left join
     b b2017
     on a.id = b.id and b.year = 2017;
```

Comment: giving an error : The multi-part identifier  could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

You can join these tables and pivot as below:

```
Select * 
from (
    Select 
        a.Id, 
        a.[Name], 
        b.[Value], 
        b.[year] 
    from tablea a
    left join tableb b on a.Id = b.id
) a
pivot (
    max([Value]) 
    for [Year] in ([2016],[2017]) 
) p
```